# Getting 2 responses from google api when I make a call using JS

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am working with Google API & javascript, and i get 2 responses from the API when i make a call. Is there a way to limit the response to the first call made?

```
const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "API_LINK_TO_CALL"
;

Http.open("GET", url);
Http.send();                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
    result = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
    console.log(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wait for the response to be ready

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

```
Http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (Http.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        const result = JSON.parse(Http.responseText);
        console.log(result);
    }
}
```